# Angularjs Login through JSon

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs

I've just started learning AngularJS.

I have to make Login Form Validation using AngularJS.
I have about 20 users are consisted of user_name and password in my JSon file and I have to login using these pairs.

```
[{"user_name":"Admin", "password":"777"},{"user_name":"Pavel","password":"000"},{"user_name":"Igor","password":"grcomerce"}]
```

Of course I was surfing looking for the answer, but didn't find.

HELP ME PLEASE!!!

Comment: https://scotch.io/tutorials/angularjs-form-validation

Comment: Sorry, I did not understand. What you want to do with your json file? And with your form? If you want to validate form data, the Scotch link will solve it.

Comment: Yes, but I have to compare entered user_name and password with the user_names and passwords in JSon.